# Is it possible to give multiple values as input in a string parameter in Jenkins job..?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to give multiple values as input in a string parameter in the Jenkins job..?
If yes, what will be the syntax and how are we calling that in a for loop so the values take one after the other.?

This is for a declarative job in Jenkins.

Thank you for the help in advance

parameters {
string(name: "usernames", value: list.join (","), description: "enter the user names")
}

stages{
need the syntax for this --> //for user in usernames list
do
$echo ---> username
this username which print will be called in my curl command one after the other.
so please do help me with the right path

Comment: Hello, can you please provide an example of code where you use this string parameter ?

Comment: Hi, I have updated a few more details in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it is only possible to pass one string.

That being said, since you are using strings you can encode whatever data you want in them.
Suppose you want to pass the pipeline a list of strings `myList` with values ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']. In the calling job you could simply do:

```
build ... parameters(string(name: "myString", value: myList.join(",")))
```

which passes 'foo, bar, baz' to the called job. There you could parse it out again:

```
params.myString.split(',') // results in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

To iterate over this, you could use a [for-in loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_forin_statement.htm) or a [list function](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_iterating_on_a_list) like each or collect.

Comment: Hello, Thank you this was helpful. But I'm still finding it difficult in understanding on how to call the values one by one in the for loop. I do have added more description on my task.

Comment: If the define --> parameters(string(name: "myString", value: myList.join(","))) getting error with "value" term .. method calls on objects not allowed outside script blocks

Comment: put it in a script block then

Answer (score 1):

In order to iterate over all the elements you receive you can use the each method

```
stages {
    stage("Iterate over parameters"){
        script{
            def userNames = params.userNamesString.split(',')
            userNames.each { user ->
                echo "$user"
            }
        }   
    }     
}
```

Alternativly (instead of the `userNames.each` block you can just use a for-in statement:

```
for(userName in userNames){
    echo "$userName"
}
```

For more informations on this please have a look at the links I included in my previous answer.

Comment: So if I'm using the for in loop , then the parameters userName and Usernames should be defined as??  parameters(string(name: "usernames", value: list.join(",")))....? And then directly use for loop as above..?

Comment: just like in the other snippet